# Why “off ” in jerk off, jack off, get off?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I wonder why the particle *off*  is used in these verbs. I know their meanings, but I don’t understand why *off*  is used. Does anyone know why?

Comment: list of similar phrases: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_phrasal_verbs_with_particle_%28off%29

Comment: I was going to say it's almost dismissive, but then remembered *kick off* (to start a ball game) and the noun *play-off* (in the sense of "tie-breaker") so that doesn't really work.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Playoff refers to the way the losing team is sent off - out of contention. Kick off referred originally to kicking the (American) football off its tee - since a kick off occurs at the start of a game (as well as other times) it's become a colloquialism for starting an endeavor. The "off"(s) in the original question have a specifically sexual meaning. Purely guessing, but it may have something to do with the opposite of being "turned on".

Comment: In a similar vein, _get your rocks off_, _beat off_, _toss off_, and _whack (one) off_.

Answer (score 5):

The *off* in those particular verb phrases is used as an adverb. The meaning I'll take [from wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off#Adverb):

1. In a direction away from the speaker or object.

   *He drove **off** in a cloud of smoke.*
2. Into a state of non-operation; into a state of non-existence.

   *Please switch **off** the light when you leave.*

So in the case of *jerk off* we're speaking of a jerking motion away from the *ahem* "object". *Jack off* is just a bowdlerized version of the phrase. *Get off* usually means to get away from (so that you're no longer on top of) something or someone, or more metaphorically to experience excitement or orgasm. In those instances, it's evoking really the "out of body" experience.

You could also interpret the meaning of *off* in *get off* to be sense 2: you're "going until you're finished."

Comment: _Take off_ with the sense _doff_, and _take off_ with the sense _become airborne_, are self-explanatory, but what about _take off_ with the sense _impersonate_?

Comment: I hear that as to "take" the personality/mannerisms "off" someone else and put them on display.